# How to make column operations between two different data frames based on a condition in pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have been trying to perform mathematical operation between two data frames Data1 and Data 2 based on a condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that for some accounts you have **more than one** operation,
**both** incoming and outgoing.

So to reflect the transfers between accounts in their balances,
in the way compliant with the rules of accounting,
you should process your data as follows:

1. Set the index in *data1* to *Account Number* (it will be needed for
   easy access to the row concerning particular accout).
2. Create in *data1* a new column called *New Balance*, initially filled with
   data from *Balance*.
3. Loop over rows from *data2* (concerning transfers between accounts).
4. In each loop read from the current row:

   - Outgoing Account,
   - Ingoing Account,
   - Amount.
5. Process the current transaction, performing the following operations:

   - locate in *data1* a row with index == *Outgoing Account*,
   - subtract the *Amount* from *New Amount* field,
   - locate in *data1* a row with index == *Ingoing Account*,
   - add the *Amount* to *New Amount* field.

The code to do it is:

```
data1.set_index('Account Number', inplace=True)
data1['New Balance'] = data1.Balance
for _, row in data2.iterrows():
    outAcnt = int(row['Outgoing Account'])
    inAcnt = int(row['Ingoing Account'])
    amt = row.Amount
    data1.at[outAcnt, 'New Balance'] -= amt
    data1.at[inAcnt, 'New Balance'] += amt
```

When you *print(data1)* after the loop, for your data, you will get:

```
                Balance  New Balance
Account Number                      
1                2356.0       1945.5
3                 452.5      -2874.5
5                 120.0       2197.0
7                 124.0         13.5
9                4582.0       4595.0
12                230.0        497.5
14                  9.5      -2001.5
16                423.0       -381.0
18                235.0        -66.5
20                 12.0       4619.0
```

This way the new balance reflects transfers performed during this business day,
e.g. for account No *1* there were performed:

- output of *$23.00* to account No *9*,
- input of *$35.50* from account No *7*,
- output of *$423.00* to account No *16*.

(the currency may be different).

So:

```
2356.00 - 23.00 + 35.50 - 423.00 = 1945.50
```

(not *2333.0* as in the other solution).

## How to handle attempts to overdraft

In the comment as of 23:32Z you asked about **reverting** transfers
leading to a negative balance of the outgoing account.

I think that instead of reverting them, the easier and more natural way is
to extend the existing loop by a check whether the outgoing account has
enough money (*New Balance* in the respective row of *data1* >= *row.Amount*).

If not then:

- neither subtraction from the outgoing account nor addition to the
  ingoing (receiving) account should be performed,
- this transaction should be marked (in *data1*) as refused.

In this variant, the code should be something like:

```
data1.set_index('Account Number', inplace=True)
data1['New Balance'] = data1.Balance
data2 = data2.assign(Refused=False)
for transKey, row in data2.iterrows():
    outAcnt = int(row['Outgoing Account'])
    inAcnt = int(row['Ingoing Account'])
    amt = row.Amount
    balBefore = data1.at[outAcnt, 'New Balance']
    if balBefore >= amt:  # The charged amount has enough money
        data1.at[outAcnt, 'New Balance'] -= amt
        data1.at[inAcnt, 'New Balance'] += amt
        result = 'OK'
    else:
        data2.at[transKey, 'Refused'] = True
        result = 'Refused'
    print(f'{outAcnt:3} {inAcnt:3}  {amt:8.2f}  {balBefore:8.2f}  {result}')
```

For demonstration purpose, I added a printout concerning both account
numbers, transfer amount, balance of the outgoing account before the
transaction and "OK / Refused" status.

This time the "trace" printout is:

```
 1   9     23.00   2356.00  OK
18  12    242.50    235.00  Refused
 7  14    120.00    124.00  OK
16   3   1227.00    423.00  Refused
20   7     45.00     12.00  Refused
 5  18     59.00    120.00  OK
 3  14      5.00    452.50  OK
 3  20   4534.00    447.50  Refused
 3   9     15.00    447.50  OK
 7   1     35.50      4.00  Refused
 9  16     25.00   4620.00  OK
16  12     25.00    448.00  OK
18  20    118.00    294.00  OK
14   5   2136.00    134.50  Refused
 1  16    423.00   2333.00  OK
```

and the final result in *data1* is as follows:

```
                Balance  New Balance
Account Number                      
1                2356.0       1910.0
3                 452.5        432.5
5                 120.0         61.0
7                 124.0          4.0
9                4582.0       4595.0
12                230.0        255.0
14                  9.5        134.5
16                423.0        846.0
18                235.0        176.0
20                 12.0        130.0
```

Print also *data2* with the added column, marking the refusal status.

## Conversion of *Time* column

Note that *Time* column in *data2* contains only digits and by default
is read as *int64* type. If you want to convert *Time* column to *time* type,
run:

```
data2['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(data2['Time'], format='%H%M').dt.time
```

To be more precise, the *pandasonic* type of this column will be *object*
(actually *something other than defined numeric data types*) but if you
attempt to read an **individual** value, e.g. `data2.iat[0,0]`, you will get
`datetime.time(9, 15)` (the same for all other elements from this column).

Comment: Amazing!!!,  What if as a next step we have to reverse only those outgoing transactions of only those account with negative balance based on the chronology of time and get new values in the column 'New Balance'

Comment: Excellent, working just fine :D, This is the last doubt, I promise: What is the way to block the smallest number possible of transactions in order for the condition that all balances be non-negative to be satisfied.

Comment: I think, there is nothing like *smallest possible number of transactions to block*. Actually, consecutive transaction are submitted by the account owner.
The are **immediately** executed and any following transaction causing an overdraft must be refused.
Note however that at some later point there can be a transaction from **other**
account to the above account and then the accout owner can submit the same
(previously refused) transaction again. If at this moment the balance is
sufficient to perform the transfer, it will be accepted.

Comment: Trust me, I've been trying this from morning and this message is displayed :Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

Comment: This is the answer I have got, what is the necessary tweaks to be done to get the code to bring in time into equation? Account Number Balance (£)
01 1910
03 447.5
05 61
07 4
09 4580
12 472.5
14 134.5
16 871
18 51.5
20 12

Comment: What are the changes to me made in the required code to bring in time into equation. Otherwise your solution was precise and impeccable.